# Shell PHP command and browser don't return the same output

Tags: php, shell, exec

Here's my script

**test.php**

```
function doc2text($filename){

    $name = pathinfo($filename,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    $count = exec('abiword --to=txt '.$filename.' && wc -w classes/'.$name.'.txt');
    $count = explode(" ",$count);
    var_dump($count);
    return $count[0];

}

echo doc2text('classes/demo.pdf');
```

When I run this script in command line like so :

```
php test.php
```

The var_dump output normally :

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "1663"
  [1]=>
  string(16) "classes/demo.txt"
}
```

But when I run the same page on my browser the array is empty :

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" }
```

This is really weird... Any clues why it's doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

`abiword` is probably not in the path of the webserver environment.  Try: `/path/to/abiword`.  Also, `$filename` will need to be in the directory of the running PHP script or you need to specify the path.

Also use error reporting:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Comment: It is since the demo.txt file is created from abiword